# Getting 401 on (Unauthorized) error when building for an Entity Framework migration

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm fairly new to the world of Code First and using EF migrations. So far it's been going okay, however, when I try and create a migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigrationName --project MyProject
```

I get a 401 error when the build attempts to restore nuget packages from my private Azure based Nuget Repo.

It all builds fine normally, and my project has no issues getting this nuget package, only when done via entity framework migrations.

I'm running the command from the Package Manager Console, and it's set to `Package Source: "All"`.

EF tool is the latest
Visual Studio 2019 Community
.Net Core 3.1 projects

What am I missing here? Does running the EF Migration tool from the package manager console not run under my account?

Comment: For those who need help with this check your feeds in VS. I had 2 private ones and it was checking there and failing with a 401. I removed them and left the nuget source and it worked.